# Enabled experiment stopped getting picked up by the analyzer

Tags: dart, dart-analyzer

I'm running Dart 2.8.0-dev.18.0 and I want to use non-nullable types. That's why I added the following to `analysis_options.yaml`:

```yaml
analyzer:
  enable-experiment:
    - non-nullable
```

Everything worked fine until it mysteriously stopped working when I turned on my computer again. No matter what I do now, I get a message saying `This requires the 'non-nullable' experiment to be enabled.`

This is a pure Dart app.

Also, when I open up Analysis Server Diagnostics, I see that the "non-nullable" feature is enabled in the **Contexts** tab.

Answer (score 0):

After much despair, the age-old advice of "delete the `.dart-tool` folder" proved to be correct.